# REGEX Query in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Having a bit of a headache with a scraping scenario I'm trying in Google Sheets.

In a nutshell, we want to use Google Sheets with ImportXML to create scraped feed from clients' websites pulling product details.

Here is a link to the smaller version of the doc. https://docs.google.com/a/sprt.co.za/spreadsheets/d/1dSbglYniWa_cijb6yDty576j33CTk9Cf8J38a3VXHSU/edit?usp=sharing

Currently this specific client only has the Item Price, etc details in a text area in the code. So when I use =ImportXml($C$2, "//textarea") it gives me the entire text area across two cells. From these cells, actually only the second one I need to pull out details but I am pretty stuck on the Regex on a piece if data this big.

```
" { ""id"": ""061013AACI9"", ""productId"": ""061013AACI9"", ""name"": ""VANS MEN'S 
PERFORATED LEATHER ERA"", ""price"": ""R 799.00"", ""oldPrice"": """", ""brand"": 
""Vans"", ""brandURL"": ""/plp/vans/_/N-1z140je"", ""defaultImages"": [ ], 
""images"": [ { ""thumb"": 
""http://tfgsrv.wigroup.co/06/Thumbnail/31460739.jpg"", ""large"": 
""http://tfgsrv.wigroup.co/06/Detail/31460739.jpg"" } , { ""thumb"": 
""http://tfgsrv.wigroup.co/06/ThumbnailAlternative/31460739_01.jpg"", 
""large"": ""http://tfgsrv.wigroup.co/06/DetailAlternative/31460739_01.jpg"" } 
, { ""thumb"": 
""http://tfgsrv.wigroup.co/06/ThumbnailAlternative/31460739_02.jpg"", 
""large"": ""http://tfgsrv.wigroup.co/06/DetailAlternative/31460739_02.jpg"" } 
, { ""thumb"": 
""http://tfgsrv.wigroup.co/06/ThumbnailAlternative/31460739_03.jpg"", 
""large"": ""http://tfgsrv.wigroup.co/06/DetailAlternative/31460739_03.jpg"" } 
], ""transientProfile"": ""true"", ""wishListId"": ""anonymous"", ""colors"": [ { 
""id"": ""31460739"", ""name"": ""White"", ""path"": 
""http://tfgsrv.wigroup.co/06/ColourSwatch/31460739_SW.jpg"", ""activeColor"" : 
true, ""available"" : true } ], ""sizes"": [ { ""id"": ""31460740_06"", ""name"": 
""6"", ""available"": false } , { ""id"": ""31460741_06"", ""name"": ""7"", 
""available"": true } , { ""id"": ""31460742_06"", ""name"": ""8"", ""available"": true 
} , { ""id"": ""31460743_06"", ""name"": ""9"", ""available"": false } , { ""id"": 
""31460744_06"", ""name"": ""10"", ""available"": true } , { ""id"": ""31460745_06"", 
""name"": ""11"", ""available"": false } ], ""productType"" : ""ColourSize"" } "
```

I need to pull out the R 799.00 value from that mess. So if anyone is willing to help out. Because frankly my talent and skill has run it's course in trying to navigate that with RegEx.

Comment: Your doc is not public, no one can view that https://docs.google.com/a/sprt.co.za/spreadsheets/d/1dSbglYniWa_cijb6yDty576j33CTk9Cf8J38a3VXHSU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, the doc is public now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
""price"":\s""([^"]+)""
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fB5kD3/1)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [124-132]   `R 799.00`
```

Comment: RegEx working nicely, thanks. ALso works for pulling other values from the Text Area so double bonus.

Now trying to get the RegEx to work in Sheets.

=REGEXEXTRACT(E3,'""price"":\s""([^"]+)""')

Isn't giving me any joy.

Comment: try this `=REGEXEXTRACT(E3,"price.*?:\s.(.*?)..,")`

Comment: `=REGEXEXTRACT(E3,"price\W*:\W*(.*?)\W?,")`  RE2 regular expression syntax reference https://re2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/syntax.html

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a lot!